# Swift: Comparing playing cards - Binary comparison cannot be applied

Tags: swift, comparison-operators

I have the following code in Swift playground where a `Card` struct is created.

I need to compare cards to see what value is higher.

Ideally, I also need to check against all forms of binary operations `<, >, <=, >=, etc`

However, I keep getting an error that says:

```
error: binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Card' operands if (ace > king) {
    ~~~ ^ ~~~~
```

A further message states:

> note: overloads for '>' exist with these partially matching parameter
>   lists: ((), ()), (UInt8, UInt8), (Int8, Int8), (UInt16, UInt16),
>   (Int16, Int16), (UInt32, UInt32), (Int32, Int32), (UInt64, UInt64),
>   (Int64, Int64), (UInt, UInt), (Int, Int), (UIContentSizeCategory,
>   UIContentSizeCategory), (Date, Date), (IndexPath, IndexPath),
>   (IndexSet.Index, IndexSet.Index), ((A, B), (A, B)), ((A, B, C), (A, B,
>   C)), ((A, B, C, D), (A, B, C, D)), ((A, B, C, D, E), (A, B, C, D, E)),
>   ((A, B, C, D, E, F), (A, B, C, D, E, F)), (Self, Other), (Self, R) if
>   (ace > king) {

```
struct Card : Equatable {

    // nested Suit enumeration
    enum Suit: Character {
        case spades = "♠", hearts = "♡", diamonds = "♢", clubs = "♣"
    }

    // nested Rank enumeration
    enum Rank: Int {
        case two = 2, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
        case jack, queen, king, ace
        struct Values {
            let first: Int, second: Int?
        }
        var values: Values {
            switch self {
            case .ace:
                return Values(first: 11, second: nil)
            case .jack, .queen, .king:
                return Values(first: 10, second: nil)
            default:
                return Values(first: self.rawValue, second: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    // Card properties and methods
    let rank: Rank, suit: Suit
    var description: String {
        var output = "suit is \(suit.rawValue),"
        output += " value is \(rank.values.first)"
        if let second = rank.values.second {
            output += " or \(second)"
        }
        return output
    }
}


extension Card {
    public static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return ((lhs.rank == rhs.rank) && (lhs.suit == rhs.suit))
    }
}

// Try to compare two cards
let ace = Card(rank: .ace, suit: .clubs)
let king = Card(rank: .king, suit: .diamonds)

if (ace > king) {
    print ("Ace is higher value")
}
else {
    print ("Ace is NOT higher")
}
```

I am wondering what I am getting wrong.

Comment: You need conformance to `Comparable` to be able to use the comparison operators.

Comment: You create a custom `==`for Card objects, but not a `<` nor a `>`, which is the `Comparable` protocol: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable

Comment: Why does jack, .queen, .king have the same value?

Comment: What's the purpose of having a second value when it is always nil?

Comment: @LeoDabus was just typing out the same question

Comment: The original code I was using was for to handle when Ace was 1 and 11.  the original code I was using it for was built for a Blackjack clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to conform to the `Comparable` protocol to be able to use the comparison operators (`<` and `>`).

```
extension Card: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rank.values.first < rhs.rank.values.first
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try:  But your version is better

`public static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return ((lhs.rank == rhs.rank) && (lhs.suit == rhs.suit))
    }
    public static func > (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return ((lhs.rank.rawValue > rhs.rank.rawValue))
    }
    public static func < (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return ((lhs.rank.rawValue < rhs.rank.rawValue))
    }`

Comment: @zardon I agree about comparing the rank property but you are implementing unnecessarily the operator `>` you just need to implement `<`

Comment: "*Types with Comparable conformance implement the less-than operator (<) and the equal-to operator (==).*"

Comment: ah, I understand. Makes sense.  Sorry, first time doing stuff with comparable, but I believe I understand what is going on